# How to get Blank Email Envelope Template

Tags: excel, vba

When I use Email Envelope method in VBA and enter TO, CC and BCC fields for the first time, during the next iteration, the first iteration/old values auto populate as soon as `ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True` is executed.

How can we make the workbook to show envelope with blank To, CC and BCC field values? I want a Blank Envelope every time, is this possible?

My piece of code:

```
Subj = "Updates"
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
       .Item.To = Sendto
       .Item.CC = Sendcc
       .Item.BCC = Sendbcc
       .Item.Subject = Subj & " - " & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
       .Item.Send
    End With
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Reset it

```
Sub SendEmailToMe()
    Sendto = "aaa@aa.com"
    SendMEcc = "bbb@aa.com"
    SendMEbcc = "ccc@aa.com"
    Subj = "Updates"

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
       .Item.To = Sendto
       .Item.CC = SendMEcc
       .Item.BCC = SendMEbcc
       .Item.Subject = Subj & " - " & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy")

       MsgBox "This is how it looks before you sent it"

       .Item.Send
    End With

    MsgBox "Press Ok to reset it"

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
       .Item.To = " "
       .Item.CC = " "
       .Item.BCC = " "
       .Item.Subject = " "
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Try `.Item.To = vbNull` instead of `""`? It should, effectively, be the same, but `vbNull` may get a slightly different result.

Comment: @UdayNeethipudi, Change `""` to `" "`. Now try it

Comment: With your last suggesting, I have figured out that it is not replacing the old value directly with "" (I mean null) but if I insert, 1 or any other value and then again try to ake it null, it is working. Most disgusting behavior I have noticed till date but somehow a temporary logic and it is working.

Comment: Now my code that resets values looks like this:
`ctiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
            With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
                .Item.To = "1"
                .Item.To = ""
                .Item.CC = "1"
                .Item.CC = ""
                .Item.BCC = "1"
                .Item.BCC = ""
            End With`